# Are internal identifiers (such as auto/local variables and labels) linked by linker?

Tags: c

> Are internal identifiers (such as **`auto`**, **local variables** and **labels**) linked by linker?

(according to my current knowledge, they are NOT. I want to ask "Am I Right?")

And another thing :
- Is it correct to say "everything with non-file-scope won't be linked by linker at all"?

Comment: Your choice of terminology is interesting; the assembler assembles, and the linker links.  Does a linker need to do anything special about names of local variables and labels?  No, the names are only seen as part of the debug information; the core linker functionality is not affected.  The runtime loader (`ld.so.1`, for example) may have to do fixups associated with local variables and labels, but it doesn't use the names for the fixup.  Similarly, static variables (whether at file scope or function scope) don't need the linker to look at the names.

Comment: @kaymas I've added an edit to my answer on the actual names of identifiers, as Jonathan seemed to correctly observe that this is what you were referring to. I hope it helps.

Comment: @BryanOlivier Thank you very much for your attention and help.

Comment: The names of local variables that are not `extern` have *no linkage*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically auto/local variables are located in a register or on the stack and thus don't require any linking. It is conceivable however that on some architectures with a limited stack, the auto/local variables of a non-recursive (either directly or indirectly) function are lifted out of the function and placed in global memory. Of course the function will not be re-entrant anymore either. In that case a symbol will be generated for this local that will be resolved by the linker. Similarly consider the following example:

```
int f(void)
{
        static int v = 0;
        return v++;
}
```

Although the scope of `v` is confined to the function `f` it will still result in global symbol that will (most likely) be resolved by the linker. I say 'most likely', because it is also possible that a compiler groups together `static` global variables and refers to them by having a pointer to the base of the group plus an offset. Thus saving on loading the address of a symbol too often.

Your statement would roughly hold, but there are exceptions to it and it may depend on the compiler and architecture.

Labels are in general handled by a linker even if they don't have export linkage.

EDIT: Taking Jonathan's observation in consideration that you may be referring to the actual names of identifiers, then in general only symbols with external linkage will be literally passed to the linker. All internal identifiers used for example for labels and static globals will be renamed to some numbered symbols. Nevertheless the linker may still be used to resolve such numbered symbols. Note that typically static functions will still retain their name even though they don't have external linkage.

Comment: The name of a label would never be seen by a linker, even in the relatively unlikely circumstance that there was some fixup associated with the label — ignoring the GCC extension for handling label variables (and even then, I don't think there'd be a name to deal with).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Wouldn't a label end up being an assembly label marking a basic block, to which a branch may have to get resolved? An assembler may resolve it with a PC relative branch, but if an absolute jump is required, I think the linker will come in. What do you think?

Comment: For PIC (position-independent code), which is what most C compilers emit most of the time these days, there's not really any absolute jumps. However, even with non-PIC code, the jump locations would all be within a single assembler translation unit, and would be sorted out by the assembler, perhaps leaving fixups for the linker and loader to deal with. However, I'm not convinced (at least until I reread [Linkers and Loaders](http://www.amazon.com/Linkers-Kaufmann-Software-Engineering-Programming/dp/1558604960)) that the linker really does anything with the labels. The loader will do fixups.

Comment: The primary task for the linker is to create the executable image (or shared library image) using the names visible outside of each object file to identify the connections between the object files and ensure that the references are properly satisfied. Debugging information is mainly copied; the linker does nothing more with that. Internal references within each object file lead to fixups which the loader may have to resolve (fix up), but don't affect which library code, for example, is used in the executable. WPO (whole program optimization) is interesting but doesn't change my conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "assembled". A linker/loader basically does three things:

- Patching addresses in at places where they are needed but couldn't be provided at compile time
- Relocating pieces of code (mostly by patching in addresses ...)
- Collecting program "segments": Data and code (by appending the pieces from the single object files)

If you look what happens with local symbols (let's stay with 'static' symbols with files scope for the moments, not auto), the compile provides information like

- I need 4 bytes of memory in the data segment, and I'm calling the address foobar.

But can it reference that address with any actual number in the code it produces? No: The data segment is either an offset from a segment register (rare these days, segmented address spaces have mostly died out) or a offset from some base address.

But the compiler can't know where in the data segment the storage will be located. So it will have to wait for the linker to supply this information.

What can the linker supply? It collects all data segment definitions from the objects files by appending them), so it knows the complete static data segment and consequently the offsets of the symbols pointing to the data segment. But can it patch in an absolute address? Well - that depends on your operating system: If there is a convention for a fixed data segment base address, the linker will already know the address at this stage of affairs.

But if it is part of the operating system configuration and process loading to provide that address, the linker can only patch in the offset to the data segment (that is a symbolic reference to "I need 4 bytes named foobar" becomes "foobar is NNN bytes form the beginning of the data segment"). It then is the operating systems program loader that has the patch in an absolute adress when creating the memory image of the process.

Things are simpler with "local" variables: Those are just offsets into the stack that can be determined at compile time  and the linker has nothing to do with them.

(I leave 'static' local variables as an exercise to the reader :-)

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The C language has the notion of *linkage*. Linkage is a property of *names* and describes the meaning of names across different translation units. The details are e.g. in C11 6.2.2..

Briefly, linkage can be either *external* or *internal* or *none*. Only the names that are identifiers of objects or functions can have linkage. For example, functions have external linkage unless they're declared as `static`, in which case they have internal linkage. Local variables that are not declared `extern` have no linkage, as per 6.2.2/6:

> The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than
>   an object or a function; an identifier declared to be a function parameter; a block scope
>   identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier `extern`.

In terms of the implementation, names without linkage do not need symbolic placeholders in the generated machine code, since they can be referred to directly. Names with internal linkage may or may not need a symbol, but if they do it has to be unique and depends only on the translation unit that declares the name. Things with external linkage are the ones subject to proper linking and need to be findable by the linker across translation units.